# how can i store the result of the selected columns in my sql query in a variable in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

```
Try
    cn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    query = "Select emp_id,emp_fname,emp_lname,empmname,position,branch from dtrsystem.tblemployee where emp_id = '" & Class1.empid & "' "
    sql = New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
    reader = sql.ExecuteReader

    cn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

i want to store my emp_id,emp_fname,emp_lname,empmname,position,branch in a variable and show it in a label. I'm new to vb.net and tried the codes i've searched but it doesnt work. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            ''declare variables    v1,v2,v3
            Try
                            cn.Open()
                            Dim query As String
                            Dim fname As String
                            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
                            query = "Select emp_id,emp_fname,emp_lname,empmname,position,branch from dtrsystem.tblemployee where emp_id = '" & Class1.empid & "' "
                            sql = New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
                            reader = sql.ExecuteReader
                while reader.read

                v1=reader(0) 'emp id
                v2=reader(1) 'emp fname
                v3=reader(2) '  emp lname
    ''etc

                End While
                            cn.Close()
                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try
```